# Convert Black to Transparency in FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, png, alpha-transparency, chromakey

I have a sequence of BMP images, which I'm concatenating to an MPNG video file, with this FFMPEG code:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -framerate 12 -i "Frame_%d.bmp" -c:v png "Video.avi"
```

I want to replace all black pixels with a transparency in the alpha layer, so it can be laid over other videos in an editor. The following code doesn't work:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -framerate 12 -i "Frame_%d.bmp" -filter_complex "[0:v]colorkey=0x000000:0.01:0.0[BlackToTransparancy]" -map [BlackToTransparancy] -c:v png "Video.avi"
```

As requested, here's the full log:

```
ffmpeg version N-93020-g3224d6691c Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 8.2.1 (GCC) 20181201
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-amf --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
  libavutil      56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
  libavcodec     58. 44.100 / 58. 44.100
  libavformat    58. 26.100 / 58. 26.100
  libavdevice    58.  6.101 / 58.  6.101
  libavfilter     7. 48.100 /  7. 48.100
  libswscale      5.  4.100 /  5.  4.100
  libswresample   3.  4.100 /  3.  4.100
  libpostproc    55.  4.100 / 55.  4.100
Input #0, image2, from 'D:\ReadOut_Process\Test\Test__Frame_%d.bmp':
  Duration: 00:00:16.83, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: bmp, bgra, 1280x720, 12 tbr, 12 tbn, 12 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (bmp) -> colorkey
  colorkey -> Stream #0:0 (png)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
Output #0, avi, to 'D:\ReadOut_Process\Test\Test__Scribe.avi':
  Metadata:
    ISFT            : Lavf58.26.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: png (MPNG / 0x474E504D), rgba, 1280x720, q=2-31, 200 kb/s, 12 fps, 12 tbn, 12 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.44.100 png
frame=   34 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 size=     774kB time=00:00:02.16 bitrate=2924.7kbits/s speed=4.21x    
frame=   65 fps= 64 q=-0.0 size=    1798kB time=00:00:04.75 bitrate=3100.1kbits/s speed=4.66x    
frame=   95 fps= 62 q=-0.0 size=    3078kB time=00:00:07.25 bitrate=3477.4kbits/s speed=4.76x    
frame=  124 fps= 61 q=-0.0 size=    4358kB time=00:00:09.66 bitrate=3692.8kbits/s speed=4.76x    
frame=  155 fps= 61 q=-0.0 size=    6150kB time=00:00:12.25 bitrate=4112.4kbits/s speed=4.83x    
frame=  185 fps= 61 q=-0.0 size=    7686kB time=00:00:14.75 bitrate=4268.5kbits/s speed=4.84x    
frame=  202 fps= 58 q=-0.0 Lsize=    9187kB time=00:00:16.83 bitrate=4470.8kbits/s speed=4.83x    
video:9176kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.112806%
```

The BMPs are too large to upload, but here's a link to a section of a typical one: https://pasteboard.co/I0RzfjI.bmp

Can it be done?

Comment: Share full log for the colorkey attempt.

Comment: Share a couple of the BMPs.

Comment: It is possible to use ImageMagik to convert each BMP to a PNG with the black replaced by transparency, and then use FFMPEG to concatenate the PNGs into an MPNG. Unfortunately, some video editors ignore the alpha layer of the MPNG.

Comment: colorkey works here with your sample. If your editor supports it, encode using `-c:v qtrle`. Lossless and has alpha support.

Comment: To clarify for anyone stumbling on this question: The code I posted as "not working" does in fact work - _but_ some video editors reset the alpha values of an imported RGBA file to FF, though their own chroma-key processing can change alpha. Reaper is like this.